# Devise current_user is nil while user_signed_in? is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm overriding Devise's confirmations controller.

```rb
class Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
    def create
        if user_signed_in?
            if current_user.confirmed?
                # ...
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Why am I getting undefined method `confirmed?' for nil:NilClass?

Should I call super at the top? Should I use resource instead of current_user? Should I call :authenticate_user! in a before_action?

What am I missing?

Thanks!